# Tkinter: Overlaying a label and buttons on top of a background image

Tags: tkinter, button, background, python-imaging-library, overlay

I would like to know how to overlaying the lables and buttons in my code on top of the background image.
Here's my code:

```
enter code here
from PIL import Image,ImageTk
root = Tk()
root.title("Sagi's Project")
root.geometry("479x700")

root.resizable(width=False, height=True)

load = Image.open('Images\\lion2.jpg')
render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(load)
img = Label(root, image = render)
img.place(x = 0, y = 0)

lbl1 = Label(root, text="Main menu", cursor="pirate", font=("Ariel bold",42),).pack()
btn_Exit = Button(root, text="Exit", font=("Ariel",21),command= root.quit).pack(anchor= 'w', side = 
"bottom")
```

[The code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jX2V7.jpg)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you need to use pure tkinter or would you be willing to use a simplified version of it?

Comment: They are overlay on top of the background image in the link picture, so what is your problem?

Comment: There are still the grey frames that surround the label and button. I wish to change it.

Comment: tkinter widgets do not support transparent background.